# Find the selected indexPaths from FXForm library -ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, fxforms

Im a newbie in iOS development. Im using `FXForm` to create a `UITableview` based form. Ive used `FXFormFieldOptions` field for multiple selection by setting the `FXFormFieldType` to bitfield. 
I need the index paths for selected options in the options list.

```
    @{FXFormFieldKey: @"language",
      FXFormFieldOptions: @[@"English", @"Spanish", @"French", @"Dutch"],FXFormFieldType:FXFormFieldTypeBitfield},
```

Could you provide some explanation or help please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a class which confirms to the protocol `<FXForm>`
2. Have a NSInteger property called language in the class you created in step 1
3. In the class you created in step 1 implement the method - (NSArray *)fields. A sample implementation is shown below.

-(NSArray *)fields

```
{
    NSArray *basicFields = @[
                             @{FXFormFieldKey: @"language",
  FXFormFieldOptions: @[@"English", @"Spanish", @"French", @"Dutch"]},
                             ];

    NSArray *controlFields = @[
                               @{FXFormFieldTitle: @"Submit", FXFormFieldAction: @"submitTapped:"},
                               ];


    return [basicFields arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:controlFields];

}
```

4. In the view controller you are displaying the form implement the method - (void) submitTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell as follows.

   -(void) submitTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell

   {

   YourClassName *form = (YourClassName *)cell.field.form;

   }

You could access the language property of the object form to get the selected index path.